# Weblogic - Received exception while creating connection for pool: "mds-SpacesDS": Socket read timed out

Tags: database, oracle, weblogic, soa

I am upgrading Oracle middleware suite from 11.1.2 to 11.1.3. When creating my weblogic domain, come to the step of testing database schema connections, it works fine (I have upgraded DEV_SOAINFRA to 11.1.3). 
However, when I start my weblogic admin server, I have this error : Received exception while creating connection for pool:  "mds-SpacesDS": Socket read timed out.

The part of the log file is:

<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <>  <1279769964111>         <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <>  <1279769964112>

> java.sql.SQLException: Socket read
>   timed out  at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:74)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:135)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:203)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:489)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:439)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:640)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:205)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:554)
>    at
>   weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.makeConnection(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:327)
>    at
>   weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.createResource(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:227)
>    at
>   weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.makeResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:1193)
>    at
>   weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.makeResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:1117)
>    at
>   weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.recreateDeadResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:2067)
>    at
>   weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.access$1000(ResourcePoolImpl.java:40)
>    at
>   weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl$ResourcePoolMaintanenceTask.timerExpired(ResourcePoolImpl.java:2442)
>    at
>   weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:273)
>    at
>   weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
>    at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
>    at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
>
> Caused By: oracle.net.ns.NetException:
>   Socket read timed out  at
>   oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:333)
>    at
>   oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:267)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1076)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:303)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:640)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:205)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:554)
>    at
>   weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.makeConnection(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:327)
>    at
>   weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.createResource(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:227)
>    at
>   weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.makeResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:1193)
>    at
>   weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.makeResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:1117)
>    at
>   weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.recreateDeadResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:2067)
>    at
>   weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.access$1000(ResourcePoolImpl.java:40)
>    at
>   weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl$ResourcePoolMaintanenceTask.timerExpired(ResourcePoolImpl.java:2442)
>    at
>   weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:273)
>    at
>   weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
>    at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
>    at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)

It seems that weblogic can't connect to the schema mds_spacesDS. I am, however, able to manually connect to the Database schema without any problem.

Does anyone encounter it before?

Khue.

Answer (score 0):

I bit late but did you see this

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1102140